# Dynamically select Namespace and Class at Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application that has a series of service references that change almost monthly. Most times the changes are minimal if any are present at all. I want to be able to select which reference to use at runtime depending on the version being targeted in a config file. For example. I may have three versions of the below NameSpace which all have Class1. Class1 may have a minor change between versions like an additional property. Any guidance would be helpful :)

```
NameSpaceVersion1.Class1 MyVar = new NameSpaceVersion1.Class1();
NameSpaceVersion2.Class1 MyVar = new NameSpaceVersion2.Class1();
NameSpaceVersion3.Class1 MyVar = new NameSpaceVersion3.Class1();
```

Comment: This sounds painful - but I would start by looking at reflection, maybe?   Another option might be DI.   I'll be interested to see the suggested answers.

Comment: Chris, do these versions of `Class1` have an interface (or anything else) in common?

Comment: No. They are independent service references with minimal differences.

Comment: Are they using in a same `dll` or different?

Comment: All in the same DLL

Answer (score 1):

If those three namespace in the same DLL

You can try to use `Activator.CreateInstance` with `Type.GetType` function.

- `Type.GetType(nameSapce)`  get class type with namespace in this DLL
- `Activator.CreateInstance` reflation create a object.

like this.

```
string nameSapce = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameSpace"];
var MyVar = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(nameSapce));
```

Setting on **webConfig**

key `NameSpace` can set which class you want to create on runtime.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NameSpace" value="NameSpaceVersion2.Class1"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is Assembly.LoadFrom(filepath/binary) see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx) and create you configured instances using Activator.CreateInstance() see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for interfaces.

However, if you cannot change the implementation (so each class implements the interface), you can create wrapper classes that do so.

Basically, create a class for each implementation that implements the target interface, but passes calls to the target implementation. You would pass the implementation class to the wrapper class in the constructor and then store it as a private field that would be used for each public member access of the interface.

Comment: Good point. Another thought I had is instead of trying to strictly adhere to service reference I could manually build the SOAP request without having any service references. I would then just have to account for the small changes by referencing the version being used in the config and wrapping those elements with IF/ELSE statements.